# Carousel ins't responsive to screen size

Tags: size, screen, carousel, responsive

**Problem**

I have had trouble with this carousel trying to get it responsive with the screen size i would love for someone to help me with this.

**Here Is The [carousel](https://www.codeply.com/go/4PubVMY8ch)**

Comment: show your code here .

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/4PubVMY8ch